# How do I display actual line numbers where errors occur in chrome developer console?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools

In the chrome developer console, line numbers are often shown of where errors occur in a program. But often it switches to indiscernible code such as shown below that I cannot discern where in the program the error is actually occurring. For instance:

```
main.19a9909fcffaac58.js:1 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'
at e.find (main.19a9909fcffaac58.js:1)
at D.ngDoCheck (main.19a9909fcffaac58.js:1)
at la (main.19a9909fcffaac58.js:1)
at ko (main.19a9909fcffaac58.js:1)
```

Is there something I can do to make Chrome show the actual line number of the program where the error is occurring?

Comment: Enable source maps in your build config.

Answer (score 0):

Your project doesn't include source maps so Chrome Developer Console prints them like how they are.

## Configure Source Maps

Source maps configuration guide: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#source-map-configuration.

## Private Source Maps

Note that when you enable source maps, people can view your code easily, formatted, etc. To prevent others from seeing your source map files formatted, you need to handle your source codes privately and not upload them with your other dist files.

### How to view backtrace with private source maps?

Well, you shouldn't try to see your errors from the browser, you must use a special service for that like https://sentry.io/ (it reports errors, collects information and you can see backtrace and breadcrumbs when the error happened).